# Javascript/JQ Content removal after certain time (timer)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I simply wonder if it's possible to make a function where you have a timer/clock which ticks and when there is no time left, a text/image will be removed. There will also be a message/text displaying notifying the user. (JQuery or Java)

I have tryed this using replace.child but without any promising result.

I have also looked around for any similar object but none found.

-Thanks.

Comment: Yes it is possible, but this site isn't really about writing your code.  Could you post what you've tried on jsFiddle?

Comment: You said what you wrote did not work, show it.

Comment: Clock; [jsfiddle][1]


  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/dAU5g/

The other is nothing i'd show here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you go:

```
(function(){
  var secondsLeft = 10,
      $timerElm   = $('#timer');

  function updateTimer () {

    $timerElm.text(secondsLeft--);

    if (secondsLeft < 0) timesUp();
    else setTimeout(updateTimer, 1000);
  } 

  function timesUp () {
    $('#target').remove();

    $('<p>works like a charm!</p>').prependTo('body').hide().fadeIn()

  }

  updateTimer();
})()
```

and here is a live demo too!
http://jsbin.com/aguyuw/1/edit

enjoy!

Comment: your welcome :) I would appreciate if you accept the answer. happy coding!

Comment: Done. (didnt see reply until now..)

Answer (score 0):

You can use setTimeout function...

```
setTimeout(function() { $('#some_id').fadeOut('slow');}, 2000);
```

here 2000 is an optional value... you can change as you concern... and if you want to fadeout fast you can use 'fast' instead of 'slow'...

For javascript you can use something like this....

```
setTimeout(function(){you_function();},3000);
```